# Converting An Array of Byte[] To A Bitmap

Tags: c#

I have a collection of Bitmaps that are stored in a `List<byte[]>` object.  I want to combine all those `Bitmap`s into one image (kinda like a paneramic) without converting them back to bitmaps. I've tried using a `MemoryStream` (see below) but it doesn't seem to work.  I always run out of memory or the image comes out corrupted.  I would appreciate any thoughts/advice on the matter.

```
List<byte[]> FrameList = new List<byte[]>();

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < FrameList.Count; i++)
    {
        //Does not work
        ms.Write(FrameList[i], i * FrameList[i].Length, FrameList[i].Length);
        //Does not work
        ms.Write(FrameList[i], 0, FrameList[i].Length); 
    }
    Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
    img.Save("D:\\testing.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 }
```

Comment: To combine jpg's you need to decode them, stitch them and encode it back to jpg

Comment: Image manipulation doesn't work like that. No structured data manipulation works like that. What you want is not possible without at least some understanding of the data format, so the condition "without converting them back to bitmaps" is not realistically possible.

Comment: You can't just add the bytes together and make a large image, there's more to that than just the raw pixel data, like headers and colour details.

Comment: Appending the bytes of one image to the end of another is like trying to make [one of these](https://i.imgur.com/INXIzdg.png) from [one of these](https://i.imgur.com/dP8EkGz.png) by doing [this](https://i.imgur.com/9R7NwMg.png).

Answer (score 1):

The steps:

1. calculate the final image size as sum of size of the individual
   images
2. create a `Bitmap` with the final size
3. get the `Graphics` object
4. draw all images using the `Graphics` object
5. save the final `Bitmap`

   ```
   var final = new Bitmap(width, height); // calculated final size
   using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(final))
   {
       graphics.DrawImage(...); // draw all partial images onto the final bitmap
   }
   ```

Comment: The requirement is "without converting them back to bitmaps." and one can't know the width and height with raw bytes.